# how to create a custom windows workflow activity using wire to connect its sub-activities

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I can create custom activities with a custom activity designer using WorkItemsPresenter. Sub-activities can be drag into my custom activity. But each of sub-activities sit side by side.

Is there a way to connect those sub-activities using wire like Flowchart or StateMachine activity?

Thanks

Comment: WorkItemsPresenter? ... I am not sure what is that. Are using Visual Studio and .Net?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you add a new Activity (.xaml file). Then use the toolbox to add a container (you can add sequence, flowchart, state machine) There is some basic tutorials for each on MSDN.
Then you add your custom activities from the toolbox (if you just added the custom activity, make sure that dll is referenced and that you have performed a build to see it)